# how to add logging in Yii?

Tags: mysql, logging, yii

I need to store some events in my Yii project:

- Create a user account on one certain time
- Update personal account
- Add more contact detail
- ....

So, what is data structure I should used with Yii Logging? Please suggest me a data table (SQL) for it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I don't master about database design, but i found the answer same your problem here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/9/how-to-log-changes-of-activerecords/ Hope it useful.